# zsh: command not found: laravel

Tags: laravel, macos, path, zsh

zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)

Here is my $PATH: in my .bash_profile

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm-packages/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin"
```

I'm not sure why the laravel command isn't being found because it used to work just fine. I have the `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` added to the path as shown in the laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x

Any ideas why this might not be working?

Comment: I've reinstalled composer and laravel and am still receiving the same issue.

Comment: Don't show us your .bash_provile, which is meaningless here, since you have used the _zsh_ tag. Show the value of the PATH variable just before invoking _laravel_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by reinstalling composer and Laravel as well as adding composer to my path within the `~/.zshrc` file. After that, running composer commands started working again. This problem was caused by my swap from bash to zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Bash and zsh are different shells and therefore use different config files.

`.bash_profile` is for bash only and `.zshrc` is for zsh only. You can change between the shells by typing their respective names as commands (`bash` will get you into bash from zsh and vice versa).